# System Center 2012: Automatically install application

Tags: sccm

I have setup a deploy for an MS Office 2013 in Microsoft System Center 2012 on a test computer using these [instructions](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-Deploying-Office-0f954e7f). On the test PC, it does not automatically install. If I go to the client's Software Center application, it is available to install. I want Office to install automatically and silently without any user intervention.

Is this possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the details on that deployment? I'm guessing you just made the deployment available, but not mandatory and required.

Comment: Which specific details?

Comment: For the deployment, there's deployment settings there's an option Action and Purpose selection, in there, you should select Install for Action, and Required for Purpose. If you can check what you currently have, that might be the cause to the problem you're having.

Comment: In the deployment settings it says Action: *Install* and Purpose: *Available*. It doesn't allow to change.

Comment: You'll have to recreate the whole deployment to change that. So recreate and change the purpose to `Required`.

Comment: It worked on my Win7 VM but not on a Win 10 VM...

Comment: Did you do any checks for OS or anything for this deployment? Depending on the settings that was selected for this deployment, there could be numerous reason why your Win7 VM got worked and the other VM didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the instructions, it skipped the step 'Deployment Settings' page in the deployment wizard where you can specify Purpose 'Available' or 'Required'.  Thus your deployment is configured as the default one which is 'Available'.

- Available = user install on demand
- Required = **Automatically** install when deadline reaches

As you have already deployed it, so you need to delete the previous deployment and create a new deployment, on Deployment Settings page, select purpose as **Required**.
[image]

I always recommend to read official document at:
[Deploy Application](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/apps/deploy-use/deploy-applications)